# How to enable an AniIndicator1 in a TThread , not in the main process in FMX?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, cursor, firemonkey

Hi I have a multidevice APP based on FMX.

The synch database process takes longer time, I need a AniIndicator1 enabled to tell user to wait.

Following code tested in n android phone,  sometime works, sometime only finish the first synch DB function, sometimes finish first 3 and then exited. Sometimes none of the sychDB function was taken place.

```
procedure TForm1.BtnSyncDBClick(Sender: TObject);
begin 
  Application.ProcessMessages;
  memo3.Lines.Add('Start synchronising...');
  AniIndicator1.Visible:=true;
  AniIndicator1.Enabled:=true;
      TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      try
        SynchDB_A;
          memo3.Lines.Add('finish 0');
         SynchDB_B;
         memo3.Lines.Add('finish 1');
         SynchDB_C ;
          memo3.Lines.Add('finish 2');
         SynchDB_D;
          memo3.Lines.Add('finish 3');
      finally
        AniIndicator1.Enabled := False;
        AniIndicator1.Visible := False;
      end;
    end
    ).start;
end;
```

So, I am wondering if I can put the AniIndicator1.enable function in a child thread and use the main thread to synchDB?

Tried following code , not working as expected.

```
procedure TForm1.BtnSyncDBClick(Sender: TObject);
    begin 
           TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      try
         TThread.Synchronize (TThread.CurrentThread,
          procedure ()
          begin
           Memo1.lines.Add('Start... ');
            AniIndicator1.Visible := True;
            AniIndicator1.Enabled := True;
          end);    
      finally

      end;
    end
  ).Start;

          try
            SynchDB_A;
              memo3.Lines.Add('finish 0');
             SynchDB_B;
             memo3.Lines.Add('finish 1');
             SynchDB_C ;
              memo3.Lines.Add('finish 2');
             SynchDB_D;
              memo3.Lines.Add('finish 3');
          finally
            AniIndicator1.Enabled := False;
            AniIndicator1.Visible := False;
          end;
end;
```

Any expert could help with this , either fix the first code to guarantee always work, child thread not being killed, or start SynchDB in the main process and enable AniIndicator1 in a child thread and make it spinning. Or any other easy way to tell user to wait while the synchDB working?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't directly access UI controls from within a worker thread, like you are doing. You MUST synchronize that access to the main UI thread.

```pascal
procedure TForm1.BtnSyncDBClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Thread: TThread;
begin 
  Application.ProcessMessages;
  memo3.Lines.Add('Start synchronising...');
  AniIndicator1.Visible := True;
  AniIndicator1.Enabled := True;
  Thread := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      SynchDB_A; // <-- must do thread-safe work!
      TThread.Queue(nil,
        procedure
        begin
          memo3.Lines.Add('finish 0');
        end
      );
      SynchDB_B; // <-- must do thread-safe work!
      TThread.Queue(nil,
        procedure
        begin
          memo3.Lines.Add('finish 1');
        end
      );
      SynchDB_C; // <-- must do thread-safe work!
      TThread.Queue(nil,
        procedure
        begin
          memo3.Lines.Add('finish 2');
        end
      );
      SynchDB_D; // <-- must do thread-safe work!
      TThread.Queue(nil,
        procedure
        begin
          memo3.Lines.Add('finish 3');
        end
      );
    end
  );
  Thread.OnTerminate := SyncDone;
  Thread.Start;
end;

procedure TForm1.SyncDone(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AniIndicator1.Enabled := False;
  AniIndicator1.Visible := False;
  if TThread(Sender).FatalException <> nil then
    memo3.Lines.Add('Error: ' + Exception(TThread(Sender).FatalException).Message);
end;
```

The reason your second code doesn't work is because the main UI thread is blocking doing all of the work, so it can't update the UI until that work is finished.  Hence the need for doing non-UI work in a thread.

Comment: thanks for your comments. The problem with your code (similar to my first version) is NOT all the synchDB functions will be executed. Sometimes only 1 executed, Memo1 only has one line "finish 0 ", then the worker thread finished. where could be the problem? this happens in Windows platform as well.

Comment: I found the problem. The synchDB has error. So it ends quietly. Will try .. finally exception can show the error message in a worker thread?

Comment: @Haizhou if a worker thread raises an exception and does not catch it, the thread will simply terminate. You need to catch the exception if you want to do anything with it. In this case, since you are using a `TThread`, you could assign an `OnTerminate` handler to the thread and check its `FatalException` property. You can also use this event to stop the `TAniIndicator`, so no need for the `try..finally` anymore. I have updated my example to show this.

Comment: You are a star, thanks for the idea. Could you give a short example of TTHread.OnTerminate coding? No idea how to implement it.

Comment: Bril, this is an excellent teaching template for multithread programming I think. Covered all the aspects. thanks  Except a small glitch at the end. It works for as

 TThread(Sender).FatalException.ToString

Comment: @Haizhou "*Except a small glitch at the end*" - fixed

Comment: are u  24x7?  :)  good to have you around , make us stronger community.

Answer (score 2):

try this, create this procedure

```
procedure TFDashboard.fnLoading(isEnabled : Boolean);
begin
  TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure begin
    AniIndicator1.Visible := isEnabled;
    AniIndicator1.Enabled := isEnabled;
  end);
end;
```

after that, you can call that procedure inside TTask

```
procedure TFDashboard.FirstShow;
begin
  TTask.Run(procedure begin
    fnLoading(True);
    try

    finally
      fnLoading(False);
    end;
  end).Start;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you call application.processmessages in a onclick event ?
You are already in main thread messages loop ...

You can also use TTask.run which is simpler than TThread.CreateAnonymousThread

```
TTask.run(
procedure
var
  msg : string;
begin
  try
   SynchDB_A;
   msg:='finish 1';
  except
    on e:exception do begin
      msg:=e.message;
    end;
  end;
  TThread.Queue(Nil,
  procedure
  begin
    memo3.lines.add(msg);
  end);
```